# cursor.execute Updating Table not updating

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table "Users" with the column "g_score". The other column I am storing are "username". I am trying to send an update to g_score via the username I get. I send the request and the value does not update. g_score is stored as an INT. I am looking to increment the value by + 1 each time.

The g_score value is default = 0
The value is not being updated by the following code

I'm going to leave some snippets here-

Creating the table -

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(username TEXT,hash TEXT,salt TEXT,g_score INT)")
```

If the user does not exist- we do

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (username, hashed_password, salt, 0))
```

This following code does not update the g_score-

```
db = lite.connect('log.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = db.cursor()


sql = ("UPDATE Users SET g_score = g_score + 1 WHERE username = ?")
cursor.execute(sql, [g_winner.get_name()])
```

Comment: Is there an initial insert which is happening for each user record, and, if so, can you include that in your question?

Comment: Did you commit the changes (`db.commit()`)?